# java.lang.illegalargumentexception - thrown by HttpURLConnection getHeaderFieldKey() method, host = null

Tags: java, html, regex, httpurlconnection, htmleditorkit

I'm trying to build a simple linkchecker application. I extract all href attributes from a webpage, and output to a file. I then check what I have parsed against a regex to check for valid URLs, and output the valid URLs to another file. I then visit those URLs and output any broken links to a third file.

In the abridged code below, it is assumed that the hrefs have already been extracted and listed in page_contents.txt. I provide the content for that text file here:

```
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/blog.html
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/teaching.html
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/research.html
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/contact.html
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/ca249/
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/ca318/
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/ca425/
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/ca651/
http://w2mind.computing.dcu.ie/
http://w2mind.org/
index.html
computers.internet.html
#world
#ireland
#uk
#multimedia
#internet
http://www.pressreader.com/
http://www.pressdisplay.com/
http://www.newspaperdirect.com/
http://www.newseum.org/todaysfrontpages/
http://news.google.com/
http://news.google.com/news?ned=uk
http://news.google.com/news?ned=en_ie
http://www.google.com/alerts
http://en.wikinews.org/
http://news.yahoo.com/
http://uk.news.yahoo.com/
http://www.apimages.com/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Media_Animation
http://www.youtube.com/user/NMAWorldEdition
http://www.youtube.com/user/NMANews
http://www.time.com/
http://www.newsweek.com/
http://www.economist.com/
http://www.salon.com/
http://www.tnr.com/
http://thenewrepublic.com/
http://www.nytimes.com/
http://www.nypost.com/
http://www.washingtonpost.com/
http://www.latimes.com/
http://www.wsj.com/
http://www.jpost.com/
http://www.smh.com.au/
http://www.theonion.com/
http://www.theonion.com/content/video
http://www.youtube.com/user/TheOnion
http://www.theonion.com/content/radionews
http://www.thedailymash.co.uk/
http://themire.net/
http://waterfordwhispersnews.com/
http://www.evilgerald.com/
http://www.langerland.com/
http://www.portadownnews.com/
http://www.portadownnews.com/archive.htm
http://www.irishurls.com/
http://www.irishtimes.com/
http://www.irish-times.com/
http://www.ireland.com/
http://notices.irishtimes.com/
http://www.irishtimes.com/search/
http://www.independent.ie/
http://www.unison.ie/irish_independent/
http://www.independent.ie/search/index.jsp
http://www.announcement.ie/
http://www.iannounce.co.uk/Republic-of-Ireland/52
http://www.sbpost.ie/
http://www.thepost.ie/
http://archives.tcm.ie/businesspost/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_Tribune
http://www.irishexaminer.com/
http://www.examiner.ie/
http://www.magill.ie/
http://www.villagemagazine.ie/
http://www.phoenix-magazine.com/
http://www.hotpress.com/
http://www.emigrant.ie/
http://groups.google.com/groups/dir?sel=gtype%3D0%2Cusenet%3Die&
http://www.listenlive.eu/ireland.html
http://www.rte.ie/
http://www.rte.ie/player/
http://www.rte.ie/tv/
http://www.rte.ie/news/
http://www.rte.ie/aertel/170-01.html
http://www.rte.ie/radio/
http://www.rte.ie/radio1/
http://www.rte.ie/smiltest/radio_new.smil
http://www.rte.ie/lyricfm/
http://dynamic.rte.ie/av/live/radio/lyric.smil
http://www.rte.ie/aertel/184-01.html
http://www.tv3.ie/
http://www.tg4.ie/
http://www.tnag.ie/
http://www.rte.ie/aertel/
http://www.rte.ie/aertel/103-01.html
http://www.irishtimes.com/weather/
http://www.rte.ie/weather/
http://dir.yahoo.com/Regional/Countries/United_Kingdom/News_and_Media/
http://www.thetimes.co.uk/
http://www.the-times.co.uk/
http://www.timesonline.co.uk/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times
http://www.thesundaytimes.co.uk/
http://www.sunday-times.co.uk/
http://archive.timesonline.co.uk/tol/archive/
http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/archive/
http://www.newsint-archive.co.uk/
http://www.newstext.com.au/
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/
http://www.independent.co.uk/
http://www.guardian.co.uk/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guardian
http://www.observer.co.uk/
http://observer.guardian.co.uk/
http://archive.guardian.co.uk/
http://browse.guardian.co.uk/
http://www.guardian.co.uk/Archive/
http://users.guardian.co.uk/help/search/
http://www.spectator.co.uk/
http://www.private-eye.co.uk/
http://www.newstatesman.co.uk/
```

I have run the program using several different pages with no problem, but with one particular page I have the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(Unknown Source)
    at test2.main(test2.java:77)
```

The error is at this line of the code

```
String name = http.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
```

Responses to previous questions around this topic suggest that the problem is that the program is reading a url's host as null. I have no idea why this may be the case (assuming that host being null is the root of the problem?). It appears that the url causing the issue is http://www.newstatesman.co.uk/ which appears to be well-formed and no different to any of the many other urls which are processed correctly by the program.

This is more or less my first question so any constructive comments on the problem or my question formulation are welcomed.

```
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.ElementIterator;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class test2 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        String fileOut2 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "page_contents.txt";
        String fileURLOut = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "urls.txt";
        String brokenLinks = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "broken2.html";


        BufferedReader URLIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileOut2));
        PrintWriter URLOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileURLOut));
        PrintWriter brokenOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(brokenLinks));



        try
        {


            String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";



            String x;

            while ((x = URLIn.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Entered while loop!");
                Pattern p =     Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

                Matcher m = p.matcher(x);

                if (m.find())               
                {
                    URLOut.println(x.substring(m.start(0),m.end(0)));  


                    URL url = new URL(x.substring(m.start(0),m.end(0)));
                    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    http.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    for (int i=0; ; i++) 
                    {
                        String name = http.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
                        String value = http.getHeaderField(i);

                        if (name == null && value == null)     // end of headers
                        {
                            break;         
                        }

                        if (name == null)     // first line of headers
                        {
                            if(!value.substring(9, 12).equals("200"))
                            {
                                brokenOut.println("<li><a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>" + " " + value.substring(9, 12) + "</li>");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println(name + "=" + value + "!!!!!!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL!!!!!");
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("IO Exception!!!!!", e);
        } finally
        {
            if (URLIn != null)
            {
                URLIn.close();
            }
            if (URLOut != null)
            {
                URLOut.close();
            }
            if (brokenOut != null)
            {
                brokenOut.close();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to include an abridged version of the code, as well as content with which to populate the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to deal with Exception in the loop, it gives you some chance to recover from bad url.

Comment: So, with my rudimentary knowledge of exception handling, I've just managed to get the program to crash at the same point with the error message that I defined.

Comment: So, my research has brought up this link - http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-css/2013Apr/0004.html - which suggests that that the problem is to do with same-domain URL redirection. "This is related to redirection but not in relation to a new domain.

This occurs when a HTTP location header specifies a relative URL instead of an absolute URL."